# C# form instantly closing

Tags: c#

All of a sudden my form window has begun to close as soon as the application is launched. There's nothing in the output window that gives a hint as to what could be causing it and there are no errors thrown at me either. Does anybody have any ideas?

I've provided to form's class.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace ProjectBoardManagement {
  public partial class CreateBoard : Form {

    Functions funcs = new Functions();

    public CreateBoard() {
      InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void CreateBoardButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) {
      String BoardName = BoardNameText.Text;
      String Pages = "";
      String Labels = "";
      foreach (ListViewItem i in PageNameList.Items) {
        Pages = (Pages + i.Name.ToString() + ",");
      }

      foreach (ListViewItem i in LabelNameList.Items) {
        Labels = (Labels + i.Name.ToString() + ",");
      }

      String BoardFile = ("board_" + BoardName + ".txt");
      funcs.SaveSetting(BoardFile, "name", BoardName);
      funcs.SaveSetting(BoardFile, "pages", Pages);
      funcs.SaveSetting(BoardFile, "labels", Labels);

      FormManagement.CreateBoard.Hide();
      FormManagement.BoardList.LoadBoardList();
    }

    private void PageNameButtonAdd_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) {
      String pagename = PageNameText.Text;
      if (pagename != "") {
        PageNameList.Items.Add(pagename);
      }
      PageNameText.Text = "";
    }

    private void LabelNameButtonAdd_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) {
      String labelname = LabelNameText.Text;
      if (labelname != "") {
        LabelNameList.Items.Add(labelname);
      }
      LabelNameText.Text = "";
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Obvious question but when debugging are any exceptions being thrown?

Comment: do debug>Exceptions - stop on exception thrown

Answer (score 0):

Obvious first thing to do - run it in Debug mode and stop execution on all exceptions. This should give you enough information on how to go from there.

Otherwise  `Functions funcs = new Functions();` looks suspicious.